# Drawing QGLWidget into a spesific rectangular area in the QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt's [hello gl example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-opengl-hellogl-window-cpp.html), QGLWidget widget is used like below(I removed the slider code to simplify)

```
glWidget = new GLWidget;
QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
mainLayout->addWidget(glWidget);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

In this case QGLWidget covers all QWidget. 
But in my case I need to draw a limited area of the QWidget I have. 
I hope my dummy drawing below will be helpful to explain my need.

```
_____________________________
|    ________________       |----> This is the widget 
|    |              |       |
|    |              |-------|--> QGLWidget should draw here
|    |______________|       |
|___________________________|
```

How can I have the GLWidget class in the example to draw into a rectangle within the QWidget class which encapsulates the GLWidget?

Comment: You can use QGridLayout to locate QGLWidget on center or glViewport to render into center rect of QGLWidget .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show just this widget in this layout it is easy.
You can do this with [setContentsMargins](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) function.

Example:

```
QWidget* myWidget = new QWidget;
myWidget->setStyleSheet("QWidget{ background: red; }");

QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
mainLayout->addWidget(myWidget);
mainLayout->setContentsMargins(100,100,100,100);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

View:

[image]

Of course, you should use correct margin values in terms of your widgets geometries like this:

```
mainLayout->setContentsMargins(this->width() / 2 ,this->height() / 2, 0, 0);
```

This code places the widget at the right bottom of widget.